# cross domain image url in container to iframe input value

Tags: javascript, image, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

I have an `iframe` that I have control of posted into the container on a different domain.

I want to grab an image url in the parent container and insert it into an`input` value in the `iframe`.

Here's my javascript code in the `iframe`:

```js
<script>
 function displayMessage (evt) {
    var message;
    if (evt.origin !== "https://container-url.com") {
        message = "You are not worthy";
    } else {
        message = "testing";
    }   
    document.getElementsByClassName('text')[2].setAttribute("value", message);
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    // For standards-compliant web browsers
    window.addEventListener("message", displayMessage, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", displayMessage);
}
      
      
  </script>
```

Here's my javascript in the `<head>` of the container:

```js
<script>
 window.onload = function () {
    var iframeWin = document.getElementById("da-iframe").contentWindow,
        myMessage =  document.getElementsByClassName('portfolio_item_image wp-post-image')[0].src;

    window.document.onload = function () {
        iframeWin.postMessage(myMessage, "https://iframe-url.com");
        return false;
    };
};
</script>
```

Im trying to take the url of an image in the container that looks like this:

```html
<img width="2000" height="1383" src="https://example.com/12.jpg," class="portfolio_item_image wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://example.com/123.jpg, https://example.com/1234.jpg," sizes="(max-width: 2000px) 100vw, 2000px">
```

and insert it into the value of an `input` in the`iframe` that looks like this:

```html
<input type="text" name="505" id="505" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="65535">
```

I'm not getting any errors. I just cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: CORS, you probably aren't going to be able to do it.

Comment: But I have control of both the iframe and the parent page. I've been told you can do it.

Comment: Not if they are on different domains.